# Remove directory if empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to check if a folder is empty and if so remove it, using the following code:

```
NSArray *folderContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:theDirectory error:&error];
if (!folderContents){
    if (folderContents.count == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"empty");
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:theDirectory error:&error];
    }  
}
```

This hasn't worked and I'm guessing I've missed something stupid but would appreciate any pointers.

- Update:
  The problem was my own stupidity - stray `!` on the second line. 
  Remove it and it works as anticipated.

Comment: Why you negated first if?

Comment: Because I'm an idiot - left a stray `!` in and posted the code here before checking it properly. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing idiot about that. It happens, silly one. BTW you earned 5 points, and helped others to earn too :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *folderContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:theDirectory error:&error];
if (folderContents) {
    if (folderContents.count == 0) {
        NSLog(@"empty");
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:theDirectory error:&error];
    }
} else {
    // log error
}
```

Comment: Thanks - didn't realise I'd left the `!` in. Me culpa.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the POSIX methods are more effective:

```
#include <unistd.h> 

if (rmdir([theDirectory fileSystemRepresentation]) == 0) {
    // directory successfully removed (must have been empty!)
} else if (errno == ENOTEMPTY) {
    // directory not empty
} else {
    // other error
}
```

`rmdir()` removes a directory only if it is empty, so no need to enumerate the directory before.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't even aware of these methods.

Comment: @Robert: It is sometimes useful that iOS is Unix-based :-)

Answer (score 1):

I guess that either "theDirectory" is nil or points to a directory that doesn't exist, because only in those cases will "!folderContents" evaluate to true. If "theDirectory" would point to an existing folder, you'd get an empty array and won't get into the "if" block.

Comment: The problem with the original code is the misuse of the `!` operator in the first `if` statement.

Comment: The original code and the current code is functionally the same. And yes, I agree, the "if( !folderContents) {}" should be removed altogether.

Comment: Actually no. The first `if` should not be removed. Only the `!` should be removed. Otherwise the 2nd `if` will evaluate as true even if there is an error and `folderContents` is `nil`.

Comment: But the initial problem was still that "theDirectory" didn't contain a valid directory, right? Otherwise your code wouldn't have printed "empty".

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what was going on there and couldn't reproduce it so I've removed that part from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSArray *folderContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:theDirectory error:&error];
//if (!folderContents)
if (folderContents.count == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"empty");
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:theDirectory error:&error];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't properly handle an error. If the call to `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` gives an error, the return value is nil. And calling `folderContents.count` on `nil` will give you `0` so you will attempt to delete the folder even if there is an error.

Comment: @duDE: Upvoted because your answer was good enough for me to solve my problem. Accepted rmaddy's because it was more complete. Thanks.